# Can't resolve sub-domain locally, running nginx on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, raspbian

just started playing with nginx for the first time and came up with a subdomain related problem.
I have a default nginx server configured (at **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**) that looks like this:

```
server {

  root /usr/share/nginx/www;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

Followed by a second server that I wish to be a subdomain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  subdomain.localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/subdomain;
    index index.html index.htm;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368/;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_buffering off;

     }
 }
```

Added a new entry to **/etc/hosts** with
    `127.0.0.1   subdomain.localhost`

I still can ping and curl my subdomain.localhost via ssh but I cannot resolve it via browser (http://subdomain.raspberrypi/ or http://subdomain.192.168.1.184/)
and everything is fine when I access my main domain.

Any ideas how to make this work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add to hosts on the machine that you using to browse
 `192.168.1.184    subdomain.rpi`